# What is the difference of concurrency::streams with std::Xstreams?

Tags: c++, concurrency, cpprest-sdk

I'm new to c++, I'm learning with the book "C++ Primer"(I am at page 710) but I'm trying to learn too how to use streams from cpprestsdk.

> How can I use `Concurrency::streams::async_istream` and
>   `Concurrency::streams::async_ostream` to take a string from the console and output that stream to console?

I have googled a lot without luck. no one use cpprestsdk today for http request and Json?
The only web who gives Info is  [CppRestSdk Documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/index.html)  and there isn't any example about anything, and [http://msdn.microsoft.com] who gives just 3 poor examples of streams, Json and http_requests.

If I'm very lost, please help me to improve my way to learn http_requests and Json in c++ giving me advices.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question asks about console I/O but you're using an HTTP library?

Comment: CppRestSDK is an Http library with asynchronous streams classes. I just want to know If they are something special compared to STD::streams and how to use this asynchronous streams

Comment: Well std streams are synchronous.  I'm not sure what your question really is now...are you asking for a tutorial?